# When trying to update I am getting this. How to solve this?

Tags: updates, 20.04

Ubuntu version: 20.04LTS Focal Fossa

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Comment: What command gives the error ?

Comment: it LOOKS like you have a broken environment.  Is this a fresh install?  Did you upgrade from an earlier release?

Comment: @Soren A. sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: @Thomas Ward I upgraded from 18.04